# Extracting a section from web page using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml, html

I want to extract the section of test for the section symptoms from the website below using python and lxml. Can anyone please help.

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/PMH0001851/

Thank you,

Comment: Does it need to be with lxml ?

Answer (score 1):

You want to Scrape a webpage with lxml? try this:

```
 from lxml.html import parse
 doc = parse("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/PMH0001851/").getroot()
 for h2 in doc.cssselect('h2'):
     print h2.text_content()
```

this will open up grab the h2s from your page.